# keycloak admin client on JBOSS AS 7

Tags: jboss, jackson, keycloak, jackson2, jackson-databind

I am not able to call **keycloak-admin-client from JBOSS AS 7.1 REST endpoint**. I am **able to call the same service from JUNIT test**, but when I try to do the same thing from REST endpoint I am having the error:

```
Caused by:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "access_token" (class org.keycloak.representations.AccessTokenResponse), not marked as ignorable
```

I am having the same error in JUNIT test when I change the dependency from jackson2 -> jackson

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

I guess its somehow connected with Jackson provider, but I tried everything from excluding jackson in deployemnt structure to using different, older version of keycloak admin client and keycloak-adapter-bom  (2.5.5 or 3.4.3).

```
<module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider"/>
```

Can anybody provide working pom.xml for keycloak-admin-client for JBOSS AS 7.1 ?

Many thanks

Comment: From the error, You have mismatch in the API versions , You should use same version of `keycloak-admin-client` as that of your keycloak server. What is client and server versions?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @ravthiru for your response.

The problem was more prozaic and simple. I have put the rest endpoint inside the war module, which is secured by keycloak adapter and that prevents the calls to any REST endpoint from outside. I have create separate war module for all REST endpoints associated with Keycloak and it works like charm. Before I called the keycloak admin client just via Unit tests, which means inside from war module and therefore I havent encountered the problem. But it cost me few days to realized where is the problem, cause I was sure it was because of jackson2.

My shame. Cheers.